# One word for data collection and data dissemination

Tags: synonyms

Is there one word (or two word phrase) for 'data collection and data dissemination"?

For example, I would like to replace

> *I am building a text based system for data collection and data dissemination*.

With something after the pattern of

> *I am building a text based system for data `<some-word>`.*

Comment: Maybe _data processing_ in general.

Comment: I am building a *data warehouse* or a *data repository*.  It is usually taken for granted that the data are being collected for some purpose -- that information can be derived from the data analysed in the aggregate.

Answer (score 1):

This may depend heavily on your use case.  The word *scraping* is used to describe certain kinds of data collection and distribution, usually on web pages:

> I sent our potential client all the data that we scraped from all our
>   competitors' web sites.

Comment: Does _scraping_ not imply that the data is being grouped, rather than distributed?

Comment: I've heard it used both ways -- my gut says that distribution is implied, but perhaps not required.  Perhaps it's purely pragmatic?  It's not a perfect match but I feel it's close

Comment: I can see how it would be implied by those who scrape data for others but I would still first envision just gathering the data when I hear _scraping_.  I could then add a statement indicating that I would send the data somewhere.  However, this means that it would not be distributed without that added statement.  For the sake of pragmatism, I would agree as it would beg the question: why scrape if not to distribute for further use? +1 for in-practice applications

Answer (score 1):

Data Management?

> I am building a text based system for data *management*

Answer (score 0):

There are several acronyms that may apply based on the software domain:

I am building a text based system for [ETL](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load)

I am building a text based system for [OLTP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLTP)

I am building a text based 
[CRUD](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) system

Answer (score 0):

> **database management**
>
> creation and maintenance of a database

Usage examples:

- High-performance computing platforms for numerical weather prediction and climate database management systems are also needed, Mukabana said.
  (Reuters,Feb 26, 2015)
- They could create the customer interface, the database management, the accounting, and the transactional interface at retail.
  (Forbes,Apr 21, 2015)

([vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/database%20management))