# Conveying Data Collection/Storage Using One Word

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing software whose purpose is to allow users to enter in a set of data to be analysed and stored, among a few other things.

I'm looking for a one word solution to let my users know that a button will take them to a page to allow for the collection(and storage of data). I've been wracking my brain for a while about this now and cannot come up with anything close, let alone elegant.

I am currently using "Record Data" as the phrase but am unhappy with it and hope there is a better fitting option.

I have also seen the question below and I'm hoping my use case is different enough. [One word for data collection and data dissemination](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/254876/one-word-for-data-collection-and-data-dissemination)

Comment: As suggested in a comment on the linked question, why not *aggregation*?

Comment: You ask for *one word* but are currently using two.  What about, "Begin Collection"?  Depending on how much your users know about your program you might get away with simply, "Start"

Comment: I think *compile* would be excellent, if it didn't already have a very specific meaning in the software context.  Here it would just be confusing to power users.

Answer (score 1):

Consider **Data registry**.

> Example: *The ESA Data Registry is a publicly accessible registry
>   describing scientific data sets on ecology and the environment. The
>   data sets registered here are associated with articles published in
>   the journals of the Ecological Society of America. They are registered
>   here in order to facilitate communication and data sharing by
>   scientists*.

I didn't proposed "data register" because this expression usually refers to internal memory storage of digital processor.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be pretty on a button, but consider:

**[Agglomerate](https://www.google.com/search?q=define:agglomerate)¹** (verb)

> 1. collect or form into a mass or group.

The way *I* see it being used:

> Press (this button) to **agglomerate** the data for analysis.

---

**¹**Oxford American College Dictionary